# Why is the reverse iterator so slow compare with the std::reverse then iterate?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int v_size = 100000;

void foo1()
{
    vector<int>test(v_size, 1);
    auto start = GetTickCount();
    reverse(test.begin(), test.end());
    int h = 0;
    for (auto& i : test)
    {
        i += h;
        ++h;
    }
    reverse(test.begin(), test.end());
    auto end = GetTickCount();
    cout <<"foo1 time consumption: "<< (end - start) << endl;
}
void foo2()
{
    vector<int>test(v_size, 1);
    auto start = GetTickCount();
    int h = 0;
    for (auto it = test.rbegin(); it != test.rend(); ++it)
    {
        *it += h;
        ++h;
    }
    auto end = GetTickCount();
    cout << "foo2 time consumption : " << (end - start) << endl;
}


int main()
{
    foo1();
    foo2();
    foo2();
    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

The result is:

```
foo1 time consumption: 0
foo2 time consumption : 156
foo2 time consumption : 156
foo1 time consumption: 0
foo2 time consumption : 171
```

I noticed two things:

First, if I replace the range for loop with a normal for loop, it becomes slower. But the time consumption is still something like 40 ms.

Second, the reverse iterator is so slow.  Why?

Comment: I don't think this is a good benchmark. You should repeat each test multiple times and mix the order, to prevent some startup issues. Furthermore, you should use a known accurate timer. If a bench results in 0 you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @JHBonarius it's 0 ms. If you increase the size of the vector, eventually you will have something. But then the foo2 will take to much time, almost minutes to finish. So I leave it like this.

Comment: Usual question, just to be sure: you _did_ compile with optimizations on, right? Because when I run in release mode I got 0 for _all_ tests.

Comment: @churill Thank you , that was the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Benchmarking is quite hard. [See this talk by Chandler Carruth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk).
I would advise to use a good benchmarking suite, e.g. [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

You can just run your Google benchmark online using [Quick Bench](https://quick-bench.com/). So just try it with the following code:

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <vector>

static constexpr int v_size = 100000;

static void foo1(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int>test(v_size, 1);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        reverse(test.begin(), test.end());
        int h = 0;
        for (auto& i : test) {
            i += h;
            ++h;
        }
        reverse(test.begin(), test.end());
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(test);
}
BENCHMARK(foo1);

void foo2(benchmark::State& state)
{
    std::vector<int>test(v_size, 1);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        int h = 0;
        for (auto it = test.rbegin(); it != test.rend(); ++it) {
            *it += h;
            ++h;
        }
    }
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(test);
}
BENCHMARK(foo2);
```

You will see that that using reverse iterators is about 3.7 times faster then using reverse (twice).

Comment: If SO had super upvotes, I'd give you one - this hit everything I'd have posted about this question including Chandler. - except your quick bench didn't have the code to actually bench it.  https://quick-bench.com/q/IlxWyK4dSX2BdWQnK1-ZylC9dAI