# Why is std::reverse_iterator slower than a direct iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, reverse-iterator

I noticed that `std::reverse_iterator` always decrements a copy of internal iterator before dereference:

```
_GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR reference
operator*() const
{
    _Iterator __tmp = current;
    return *--__tmp;
}
```

This is the implementation in GNU standard C++ library. [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator*) implements it the same way.

**The question:** wouldn't it be more efficient to decrement it just one time in reverse iterator constructor instead of decrementing it at every dereference step?

Comment: The problem is the reverse end iterator, which is the range's `begin`. You can't decrement it, yet you must be able to construct from it.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65369996/5447906)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question: wouldn't it be more efficient to decrement it just one time in reverse iterator constructor instead of decrementing it at every dereference step?

Efficiency is irrelevant when it's not possible to implement reverse iterator that way. Consider a reverse iterator representing `rend`. In order to get to it, you would have to decrement the internal iterator so that it points before the first element. That's not possible, so the decrement must be delayed until indirection where the impossibility is fine because end iterators are not dereferencible.

Comment: Why not introduce before beginning iterators? I guess `std::vector` is only container where before beginning iterator is probably not possible in general. But it is still possible on most platforms.

Comment: @anton_rh Don't forget that arrays have iterators too: pointers. Changing the rules of pointers and arrays would be a fundamental change to the language and not something to be taken lightly.

Comment: @anton_rh Having a pointer to the element before an array would be ill formed. It works on most platforms but it's nothing any C++ library can rely on because it doesn't have to always work. And changing what is allowed for pointers in the standard would be a huge change.

Comment: @anton_rh • `int main() { int arr[10]{ 1, 2, 3 }; int* p = arr; --p; }` the `--p;` is **undefined behavior**.  You can have a pointer to arr from `&arr[0]` to `&arr[10]` (but you cannot dereference `arr[10]` which is one past the end of the rray; only that the address is guaranteed to be valid).

Comment: @anton_rh Even if you allow pointers "before the beginning" of an array, it may not work the way you expect. For example, consider an array of `struct large { char buffer[1000000]; };` that happens to be allocated at address `500000`. The "before the beginning" pointer underflows and becomes a very large positive number, which means that you have the situation that the pointer "Before the beginning" of an array is actually greater than all the pointers into the array. (Having pointers "before the beginning" was considered by the committee and rejected for reasons like this.)